# Collada import has frames compressed

Tags: collada

I have a COLLADA file that I exported from Poser that I'd like to import into Blender. The file comes in nicely, and the motion is displayed properly on the mesh. However, in Poser there are 30 frames that I export. Yet Blender only imports 24 frames, with the final frame being the same as that in Poser. I would like my frames to be one-to-one between Poser and Blender.

I checked the file and it has "count = 30" all over it, so Blender should see that there are 30 frames.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: In Output Properties, Scene, Format, you can set the Frame Rate.

[image]